# Why do we set status response?

Tags: spring-mvc

In many tutorials, i Have seen the code below :

```
response.setStatus( ...);
```

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `response` refers to an HTTP response, the `setStatus()` method is used to let the user-agent know whether the result of the HTTP request is OK, or if there was some kind of Error.

Comment: Why do we need to that manualy, if there is any error, the user-agent will still get the error, am i wrong? i mean, in which situation do we really need to use it?

Comment: You must do it because your servlet is generating the response that is sent to the user-agent. The user-agent won't be able to automatically determine that there is an error.

Comment: @stunaz - you are wrong.  How will the user-agent get the error if the response code is not set?  Sure ... the response might contain an HTML document that tells a human being "<p>Error - the sky is falling</p>" ... but the user-agent (the browser) doesn't grok human language.